# How to add text next to the Hamburger Menu for small screens in MAGENTO 2

Tags: magento2, menu

Some Customers do not know that the hamburger icon is the menu for small screen on magento 2. I want to add some text next to the icon. What is the best way to do that? What files contain the code of the menu?

[image: Like This]

Answer (score 0):

You can find the code related to this in

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header/logo.phtml
```

Once you add the required text you have to do necessary changes to css files.

```
<span class="nav-toggle-msg"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Menu') ?></span>
```

To hide msg from desktop

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    .nav-toggle-msg {
        display: none;
    }
```

Comment: I used the code above, the Menu text is displayed to the right of the logo. Also It is not clickable.